# Recovery from Vim escape key error in insert mode ^[

Tags: vim

I use the [Pydiction](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=850) plugin for insert mode code completion, 99% of the time it's fantastic but occasionally I run into a problem where (after a completion) my escape key gets munged, when this happens I can't get out of insert mode, typing escape prints `^[`.

I've had to kill Vim to recover.

Vim in still responsive, is there anything I can do to reset?

Comment: try Ctrl-C, does it produce ^C?

Comment: While in insert mode, press `<c-o>` — you should return to normal mode for one command. If it works, run `:imap <Esc>` to see if something is mapped to <Esc> in insert mode. That could give you a clue to solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try remapping Esc to something else (I find it way more useful to have it mapped to caps lock)